# PDO class construction in OO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is executing an sql query okay if I'll do it inside a class? Because I do want to use DRY formatting to use execute prepare fetch all the time when executing queries. Is it okay when talking about performance and speed in PHP?

```
class foo{

protected function dbConnect() 
{
    $con="mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname";
    try{
     $conn=new PDO($con, "user", "password");
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
    }
    catch (PDOexception $e)
    {
    die ("error: ".$e->getMessage());
    }
    return $conn;
}

public function selectQuery($query,$fieldsvalues,$type)
    {
        $executequery=$this->dbConnect()->prepare($query);
        $executequery->execute($fieldsvalues);
        if($type=='fetchColumn()')
        {
            return $queryexecute->fetchColumn();
        }
        if($type=='fetch()')
        {
            return $queryexecute->fetch();
        }
        if($type=='fetchAll()')
        {
            return $queryexecute->fetchAll();
        }
    }

public function otherQuery($query,$fieldsvalues)
    {
        $queryexecute=$this->dbConnect()->prepare($query);
        $queryexecute->execute($fieldsvalues);
        return  $queryexecute->rowCount();

    }

}

$newquery=new foo();
$newquery->selectQuery("SELECT foo from bar where foobar='?'",array('baz'),'fetchColumn()');
```

Comment: Are you just asking if using classes causes performance impact?

Comment: You can use `switch...case` instead of `if($type=='fetchColumn()')`

Comment: Oh thanks. I forgot to change that.

Comment: No, there's no appreciable penalty for using classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Barmar. I am just a little bit concern in terms of speed because I WILL execute queries most of the time and I thought if that would hurt, maybe I'll switch to procedural ones.

Comment: Worry about performance problems when you encounter them! Write good code before that.

Comment: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

Comment: Yeah and I think I am one of them. I'll try NOT TO be ONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't the object-oriented class that hurts performance in your example.  It's the fact that you open new connection to the database every time you run a query.  You should open the connection once, and reuse it on subsequent queries.

Here's an example:

```
class foo{

protected $dbconn = null;

protected function dbConnect() 
{
    if (!$this->dbconn) {
        $con="mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname";
        try{
            $this->dbconn=new PDO($con, "user", "password");
            $this->dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        }
        catch (PDOexception $e)
        {
            die ("error: ".$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    return $this->dbconn;
}

. . .
```

This way, the first query will create the connection, and subsequent queries will find that the connection is still set, so it'll skip recreating the connection.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store the connection handle in a static variable?

Comment: @Bojangles, depends on if you want to create more than once instance of the class `foo`, each with a connection to a different database.

Comment: That's true, although the most likely use case is multiple instances pointing at the same database, hence my comment

Comment: @Bojangles, if that matches the application needs, then yes, one could store the DB connection as a static member of the class, to share it among multiple instances of the `foo` class, further reducing the need to open a new connection.